# When is enum instance created in java?

Tags: java, enums

When is an enum instance created in java?

1. When application loads/application startup?
2. Or is it lazy loaded i.e. it will be created only when it is required for the first time?

If I never use an enum instance in my application, will it still be created and consume memory?

Comment: Enum instances, like any other instance of anything, are created when they are needed.

Comment: An `enum` type is just a special class. Its constants are `static final` fields. The same rules apply.